# Can't get any sound out of AUDIOTRAK MAYA-U5 USB Sound Card [5.1]

Tags: 16.04, usb, sound, kubuntu

I bought this [AUDIOTRAK MAYA-U5 USB Sound Card](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B005HBP8KE) - [(Official Product Page)](http://audiotrack.net/en/usb/531) and while it works perfectly plug-n-play on Windows, I am unable to get any audio out of the device on `Kubuntu 16.04`.

I've done what I could in terms of configuring it and setting it to 5.1, turning the volume to max, testing the speakers, installing updates, and rebooting but no luck.

I tested the device in a virtual machine using USB 3.0 pass-through and while the audio quality was terrible, it did 'work'.

At first, Kubuntu only recognized it as a Stereo output. Rebooted once and then it recognized it as a potential 5.1 output but for some reason I couldn't turn the volume up past 47% without it resetting to 0%. Rebooted again and I could max the volume but still no sound output.

What's missing?

---

```
sudo aplay -l

**** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
card 0: SB [HDA ATI SB], device 0: ALC892 Analog [ALC892 Analog]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: SB [HDA ATI SB], device 1: ALC892 Digital [ALC892 Digital]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: U5 [MAYA U5], device 0: USB Audio [USB Audio]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: U5 [MAYA U5], device 1: USB Audio [USB Audio #1]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
```